# Creating a new group and setting permissions in Active Directory using C#

Tags: c#, permissions, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

I'm trying to build an app that creates some default users and groups in Active Directory.

I've managed to find this code, for creating a new group, but I don't know how to add/remove permission to the group after being generated.

This is my code for creating a new group:

```
static void CreateNewSecutiryGroup(string ouPath, string name)
{
    try
    {
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + ouPath);

        DirectoryEntry group = entry.Children.Add("CN=" + name, "group");
        group.Properties["sAmAccountName"].Value = name;

        group.CommitChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

Please help,

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code which shows how to 1.) obtain a user object via `GetUser`, 2.) check if the user (or any other `DirectoryEntry`, really) is already a member of the group via `IsGroupMember`, and 3.) add the user (or any other `DirectoryEntry`) to the a group via `AddEntryToGroup`.

```
private static DirectoryEntry GetUser(string withUserAccoutName, string inOUWithDNPath)
{
    var ouEntry = new DirectoryEntry(inOUWithDNPath);
    var searcher = new DirectorySearcher();
    searcher.SearchRoot = ouEntry;
    searcher.Filter = string.Format("(& (objectClass=User)(sAMAccountName={0}))", withUserAccoutName);
    var searchResults = searcher.FindAll();

    if (searchResults.Count > 0)
    {
        return searchResults[0].GetDirectoryEntry();
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}

private static bool IsGroupMember(DirectoryEntry entryToCheck, DirectoryEntry ofGroup)
{
    foreach (var memberPath in (IEnumerable) ofGroup.Invoke("Members", null))
    {
        var memberEntry = new DirectoryEntry(memberPath);

        if (((string) memberEntry.Properties["distinguishedName"].Value).Equals(((string) entryToCheck.Properties["distinguishedName"].Value), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

private static void AddEntryToGroup(DirectoryEntry toAdd, DirectoryEntry toGroup)
{
    if (!IsGroupMember(toAdd, toGroup))
    {
        try
        {
            toGroup.Invoke("Add", new[] { toAdd.Path });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e.InnerException; // unwrap the exception and throw that.
        }
    }
}
```